# Cronjob run program only if other programm is already running

Tags: cron

how do i run a cronjob only when another service is already up running and while the programm itself is not already running? It is important that programm2 starts only after programm1 is already up.

*/2 * * * * check if programm1 one is running ; check if programm2 is not running ; /etc/init.d programm2 start

Comment: Services that depend on other services... sounds like a task for [systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21830670/4325768).

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script using the `$?` variable. This variable contains the exit status of the last program; so if you run `systemctl status dnsmasq` and it's active, running `echo $?` will return `0` which means true. If it's not active, `$?` will return a non-0 answer, which means false.

A simple script to achieve this function would be:

```
#/!bin/bash
x=1
while [ "$x" != "0" ]
do
 systemctl status (service to monitor)
 if [ "$?" = "0" ]
 then
  systemctl start (service to start)
  break
 else
  sleep 30
  continue
 fi
done
```

Line 1 = sets a variable to non-zero so a loop can be run from it

Line 2 = starts a loop that runs continuously (x can never = 0)

Line 4 = checks if a service is running, which sets `$?` to a zero or non-zero 
value

Line 5 onward = checks if the exit status of the last command (checking if the service is running) was true or false. if it's true (zero), it starts the next service and breaks out of the loop. If it's false (non-zero) it returns to the start of the loop and runs until the selected service is running.

You could either run this script at startup or turn it into a service of its own.

You would need to run it as root, whichever your choice, since you're starting/stopping system services.

Comment: You are re-implementing the `systemd` attributes [`Requires=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Requires=) and/or [`BindsTo=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#BindsTo=) and/or [`After=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=). Also, the `while` loop will probably make the CPU fans blow because it re-runs `systemctl` without any pause.

Comment: @perlduck added a 30 second sleep in the `else` statement to address the inefficiency of running the script continuously. In regards to the former, the asker wanted a cronjob so I figured a simple script would be the most flexible solution, though not the most efficient. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @Minty if this script is called by the cronjob mentioned by the asker, wouldn't this queue a new instance of your script every 5 minutes if the service it is waiting for is not running? If you're already using systemd, you might as well use systemd timer instead of cron and the mechanisms mentioned by PerlDuck for a pure systemd solution.